# jSingleton should be replaced with single or multiple interfaces. What does this actually mean?

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, tdd

I have come across an article about TDD where author mentions Singleton as an anti-pattern, and in order to avoid this, one solution is that a Singleton should be replaced with single or multiple interfaces. What does this actually mean? An example will be much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a singleton is accessed such as `SingletonInstance si = SingletonInstance.getInstance()`. There are two steps to migrating away from this for TDD.

The first is to not use `SingletonInstance` directly, but as the author says "a single or multiple interfaces", such as `SingletonService ss = SingletonInstance.getInstance()` such that the service API `SingletonService` is an interface which the instance implements. For the "multiple" case, the singleton API may be broken up into interfaces that each have smaller but cohesive scope so each interface obeys the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

The second step, particularly for TDD, is to inject the instance rather than look it up. If your module knows how to find what it needs, then it is coupled too much to mock simply. However, if your module is provided with the services it needs (via constructor, mutators, DI, etc.) then your mocking framework can easily test your module with a mock service that implements the API enough to perform your testing.